# How to use a lambda function to add query parameters to a static site url

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, gatsby

This is an exploratory question to make sure this is possible. We would like to build a static site with [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org) and host it on an amazon S3 server. We would then like to have it served up via Cloudfront. However, before it gets to the static site, we are hoping to detect the location of the user to serve them relevant content.

So, the question is if someone hits the url https://myurl.com , can we run a lambda function that processes some information and then based on the results (assuming the function determines which one of our locales to direct them to), returns a url like this: https://myurl.com/?location=nyc-midtown

Any ideas how to append that to the url before serving up the initial html?

Comment: If it is a static site, how will you serve "relevant content"? How/where will `?location=nyc-midtown` be processed?

Comment: Some related ideas: https://medium.com/merciba/geo-fencing-users-with-lambda-edge-and-cloudfront-2eb32b531f51 and https://pracucci.com/ip-based-geolocation-with-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway.html

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I haven't tested it yet, but was planning to implement this: https://medium.com/@chrisfitkin/how-to-get-query-string-parameter-values-in-gatsby-f714161104f

Comment: @jarmod those are some good references. I wish the geolocation tools could do more than identify countries, in this case states would be better, but it seems a call to something like this might be necessary: https://www.maxmind.com/en/solutions/geoip2-enterprise-product-suite/enterprise-database

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to use a query string or can you redirect based on CloudFront headers?  Lambda@Edge may be of use to you here. Specifically the origin request event:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-redirecting-examples

Comment: Hoping to use query strings to pass that data so the urls retain the information. But this is definitely going to be part of the solution.

Comment: @Starfs Did you find a solution for adding a query string in the request to the origin ?

Comment: @ilibilibom sorry for the late reply. I don't have access to that project any more. But I believe we came up with a totally different solution.